# personalize UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have implemented a UIScrollView for my game board, this board is a UIView consists of several images, the image of the board and some images of detail. And the zoom and scroll work well.
But what I do is that when I move the board will not let me get out of the board and see the bottom. Right now when I move the board around the edges sometimes see white, as my picture moves more than up to the stop.

What I want is to put a cap on scrollview not see what's behind only see the board.

I would also like to know if any of you know how I can do to drag images as a given within the board, as this all in a UIScrollView and I recognize there touch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want is to put a cap on scrollview not see what's behind only see the board.

Yes, you can limit the visible area to just your content. Set the scroll view's [`bounces`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces) property to `NO` and make sure that the `contentInset` is 0. (0 is the default for `contentInset`, so it should be fine if you haven't changed it.)

> how I can do to drag images as a given within the board

Scroll views have the option to delay touch events in the content view until the scroll view decides whether or not the user is trying to scroll. Read about the [`delaysContentTouches`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches) property. You'll probably want to leave that property set to `YES`. Beyond that, you really just need to learn to monitor touches -- you can drag a view by adjusting its position (by setting it's `center`, for example) as a touch moves around the screen. There's some sample code that may help you in [Handling Swipe and Drag Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW21).